# Windows 10 - Change volume with scroll on icon

Tags: windows-10

I am used to hover my mouse over the volume icon. And when I scroll it changes the volume.

This works on windows 7 & ubuntu 16.04,14.04.

How can i make this work on windows 10?

Windows 10 requires me to click on the icon and open the volume slider before being able to scroll

Answer (score 3):

There are third-party programs that include this functionality. Not only for the volume icon but the whole taskbar. I found these three:

- [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker)
- [Volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html)
- [Volume²](https://irzyxa.blogspot.nl/p/downloads.html)
- WheelsOfVolume (couldn't find an official website, [google it](https://google.com/search?q=WheelsOfVolume))

And this is an [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/) script you could use ([found here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/61648-change-volume-by-scrolling-mouse-while-hovered-over-taskbar/?p=388684)):

```
$WheelUp:: 
$WheelDown:: 
MouseGetPos VarX, VarY, CurrentWindow 
WinGetClass Class, ahk_id %CurrentWindow% 
Vol := SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 7)
Key := SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 2)
If Class = Shell_TrayWnd 
    Send {Volume_%Vol%}
Else
    Send {%Key%}
Return
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) for **minimum required information** and other suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if included link(s) breaks please [edit] these details into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported in Windows 11. So, we can now change volume by hovering and scrolling the mouse wheel over the speaker icon in notification panel.